# How can i show the last value from a label each time?

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem is that for example temperature_label was on 47 and label8 also on 47.

In the next itertion lets say temperature_label drop down to 42 so next itertion label8 will be also 42. But i wanted that label8 will stay on 47 since this is the last highest value. Only if temperature_label will get sometime above 47 then update again label8.

So if temperature_label is same value no change or above the last value update label8 .

If temperature_label is under the last highest value dont update label8.Last highest value i mean if temperature_label was on 70 and now its on 60 for long time dont update label8 but if it will get ot 71 update label8 a 71 and keep it 71 and update label8 only if temperature_label get above it.

But now as thecode is now label8 will get update even if temperature_label will drop down from the last value.

I dont want to update label8 with the last value like now but the last highest value. And update label8 only if the last highest value is changed above it.

Not the current value it could be that temperature_label and label8 will have the same value but if temperature_label drop down label8 does not. And if temperature_lable get up from the last highest value then update label8 again. This is the conditions i need to be.

The code:

im getting exception error on the line: if (UpdatingLabel(sensor.Value.ToString(), temperature_label.Text.Substring(0, temperature_label.Text.Length - 1)))

The exception is: ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=length
  StackTrace:
       at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
       at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
       at Bursa.Form1.timer2_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Form1.cs:line 369
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Bursa.Program.Main() in D:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The code after the changes i did according to your code:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();
            computer.GPUEnabled = true;


            foreach (var hardwareItem in computer.Hardware)
            {

                if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
                {
                    foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                    {
                        if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                        {
                            sensor.Hardware.Update();

                            if (UpdatingLabel(sensor.Value.ToString(), temperature_label.Text.Substring(0, temperature_label.Text.Length - 1)))
                                label8.Text = temperature_label.Text;
                            temperature_label.Text = sensor.Value.ToString() + "c";

                            label8.Visible = true;
                            int t = temperature_label.Text.Length;
                            if (t > 3)
                            {
                                temperature_label.Location = new Point(238, 200);
                            }
                            timer2.Interval = 1000;
                            if (sensor.Value > 90)
                            {
                                Logger.Write("The current temperature is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                button1.Enabled = true;
                            }
                            this.Select();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }     
        }


        private bool UpdatingLabel(string newVal, string oldVal)
        {
            int intVal1 = int.Parse(newVal);
            int intVal2 = int.Parse(oldVal);
            if (intVal1 > intVal2)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the current value of temperature_label before updating it and set it to Label8

```
if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
{    
   sensor.Hardware.Update();
   label8.Text =  temperature_label.Text 
   temperature_label.Text = sensor.Value.ToString()+ "c";
   label8.Visible = true;
   int t = temperature_label.Text.Length;
   //remaining code 

}
```

Comment: Shyju not good . I tried this code i will update my question but im getting exception and dont know how to fix it.

Comment: what is the exception. did you debug using visual studio breakpoints ?